# How to load the table in DataGrid Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql

when I tried to load the table into DataGrid Control, It showed the following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'TRAINING.Employee' to
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?).

Below the code What I wrote

```
MyDatatBaseDataContext MyDB = new MyDatatBaseDataContext();
Employee Add = new Employee();
Add.EmpID = 5039;
Add.Age = 25;
Add.Address = "West Street";
MyDB.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(Add);
MyDB.SubmitChanges();

grd_1.ItemsSource =Add;
```

Comment: the datasource of a grid should implemente IEnumerable, like a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ItemsSource` property needs to be an `IEnumerable` of some type.

So if you changed the end of your code to ...

```
IEnumerable<Employee> adds = new [] { Add };
grd_1.ItemsSource = adds;
```

It might help but, do you actually want to use a grid to show one employee, with a column for each property? Do you actually want a grid of name value pairs for each property?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should bind the grid to a list of employees, something like this :

```
List<Employee> lst = new List<Employee>();
Emplyee emp1 = new Employee();
lst.Add(emp1);
grid.ItemsSource = lst;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you only have to set

```
grd_1.ItemsSource = MyDB.Employees;
```

because your [`Table<TEntity>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358844.aspx) Employees is an `IEnumerable`. I'm not sure if the added Item will show immediately but I think at the latest it will do after SubmitChanges.